# Is there a corpus of English adjective, adverb, etc metadata?

Tags: nlp, corpora

For example. In the sentence fragment "red leather stool", red is a color, leather is a covering of the stool, and stool is a chair.

Is there any database, corpus or repository, that lists the applicable modifiers of objects (eg: chair, car, etc)

Comment: Yes there is a good online database of English collocations. It goes by words though, not by objects. That is it knows about parts of speech but does not know ontologies (how the world works etc). I cannot recall its name or location right now so just a comment so far ...

Comment: You're probly thinking of [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). There is also [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/), on a larger scale, dealing with situational frames and metaphor themes.

Comment: I have use WordNet & Framenet in the past. Neither has ontological information of the type I was curious  about

Answer (score 1):

Though your exact research purposes are not quite clear, based on your specs, I believe the University College London English Usage Resources (http://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/resources/index.htm) would be a good place to start with. (Though it is diacronic 1950's to 1990's, methinks.)

Similarly, the Boston University Noun Phrase corpus also has a pretty decent search facility: http://npcorpus.bu.edu/cgi-bin/search.pl

But, probably in terms of breadth, Brigham Young University takes the lead with its incredible list of corpora: http://corpus.byu.edu/

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if openCyc has what you are looking for - but the documentations is diabolical.